# Permission Set->Flow Access available flows is empty

Tags: visual-workflow, permission-sets, access

I have Screen flow Unlock Record
[image: Unlock Record]

And want to set access for it to permission set

But in flow access window there are no flows.
[image: flow access]

Could you please help me figure out why so?

Comment: Check flow security (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_security.htm&type=5)

Comment: @Vinay, thanks, but I haven't found any information there anything that clears my mind. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- "Run Flow" permission lets you run all flows by default
- On the list of Flows, click "Edit Access" on the right-hand end picklist.  This will let you Override the default for one Flow at a time; the selected profiles (you can't do this for Permission Sets here) will see the Flow listed in their Enabled Flows list.
- The result is that if you override the default behaviour, that flow won't be accessible to any user with a profile that isn't on the list, even though they have Run Flow permission.
- You can then add the flow(s) where you have overridden the access, and add them to Permission Sets, one permission set at a time

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer. Please accept the better one Dmitriy Bereza.

Comment: @haryadoon, do you know the permission that lets one see the "Edit Access" option? It does not appear for my user/profile.

Comment: Manage Flows...

Answer (score 1):

The **System Permissions** -> **Run Flow** inside the permission set should be active, to see the flow

Answer (score 1):

Embellishing @haryadoon helpful answer with images.

On your list of flow click the dropdown and select **EDIT ACCESS**.

[image: Dropdown Edit Access]

Then select the Override default behavior checkbox.

[image: Checkbox for Override]

Finally:

1. Go to the Guest User Profile (navigate there from your Digital Experience)
2. Go to Flow Access
3. Add available flows to enabled

[image: Move Flow to enabled]