# How to enable flow access?

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions

I have a user who needs to execute a **screen flow** but gets an error :

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

He has a permission set assigned with the permission `Run Flows` enabled. When I go to the `Flow access` session, I can't add any flow because the `Available Flows` listbox is empty.

I searched on trailhead and Salesforce help (maybe not enough) but couldn't find the purpose of the `Flow access` section.
I checked this question : [Permission Set->Flow Access available flows is empty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328605/permission-set-flow-access-available-flows-is-empty) but as I told the `Run Flows` permission is enabled in the permission set.

Note that there are many autolaunched flows in the org and as far as I know (but I'll check it) they work because if they didn't that would be a mess...

So my questions are

1. Why can't I see the flows list in the `Flow access` section ?
2. Is that the right place to allow my user to run his screen flow ?
3. If not, what shoul I do ?

Last thing, the log when trying to run the flow is almost empty :

```
50.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
08:48:54.0 (285307)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0053W000000xxxx|user_email@example.com|(GMT+01:00) heure normale d￢ﾀﾙEurope centrale (Europe/Paris)|GMT+01:00
```

That's all I get !

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Just noticed : the status of the log is Success, even though I got an error message...

Comment: In production the error is not exactly the same, the message is "Une erreur non gérée s'est produite dans ce flux
Une erreur non gérée s'est produite pendant le traitement du flux. Pour plus d'informations, contactez l'administrateur système." So probably the flow is run and there's an error in the execution. That does not tell me why the list is empty though

Comment: Your error message sounds like the user's access to the records that flow is trying to access, rather than the access to the flow itself.

Comment: You're right the problem was access to some fields used in the flow. Does anyone know if the Flow access section in profile/permset has any function ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Run Flows` & `Manage Flows` permissions enables a user to be able to run flow or create/ edit flow respectively, in general. `Run Flows` should be sufficient for a user to be able to run the flow, unless you want to override this default behavior and have the flow run by users with specific profiles or permissions sets.

> Why can't I see the flows list in the Flow access section ?

Check out this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_security.htm&type=5), specifically how to edit access for individual flow. make it available in the flow access section for a specific profile.

I think the problem you are having is due to record, object or field level access (not due to lack of access to run flow). So, refer to this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) to understand under which user context your flow is running. As mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_running_user.htm&type=5), Org-wide default settings, role hierarchies, sharing rules, manual sharing, teams, and territories also impact what data is accessible to flows that run in user context. You might have to enable record level access or go to `Object Settings` in the profile to enable relevant object level & field level access.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot for your help, especially since all answers were in salesforce documentation.